# "Already exists" while pooling

Tags: docker

I start MySQL docker starts and run fine:

```
 docker run -d `
     --network todo-app --network-alias mysql `
     -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql `
     -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret `
     -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos `
     mysql:5.7
```

But what does line `69692152171a: Already exists` means? Command `docker images` brings nothing with  id 69692152171a.

```
Unable to find image 'mysql:5.7' locally
5.7: Pulling from library/mysql
69692152171a: Already exists
1651b0be3df3: Pull complete
951da7386bc8: Pull complete
0f86c95aa242: Pull complete
37ba2d8bd4fe: Pull complete
6d278bb05e94: Pull complete
497efbd93a3e: Pull complete
a023ae82eef5: Pull complete
e76c35f20ee7: Pull complete
e887524d2ef9: Pull complete
ccb65627e1c3: Pull complete
```

UPD
Below is output from `docker image inspect mysql:5.7` but there is nothing about 69692152171a

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:2c9028880e5814e8923c278d7e2059f9066d56608a21cd3f83a01e3337bacd68",
        "RepoTags": [
            "mysql:5.7"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "mysql@sha256:a682e3c78fc5bd941e9db080b4796c75f69a28a8cad65677c23f7a9f18ba21fa"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2021-05-12T08:11:03.343403499Z",
        "Container": "db38503d38cc5342a2e11abace95c67ea3cc8bb65b48d45bfcda4bcb30748245",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "db38503d38cc",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.34-1debian10"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"mysqld\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:4b62934a5405f45c27bf212c6289792743498ce4ff0a5e0f1cdf6b6371320fbf",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.34-1debian10"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:4b62934a5405f45c27bf212c6289792743498ce4ff0a5e0f1cdf6b6371320fbf",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 446995706,
        "VirtualSize": 446995706,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b355447174887cc24e9c4ce3d03bf66a43f9f12933a51d67447e6e7d3440f68/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4a933d2f6392c6e7a6bde1a2ec07796647afb48bfd3786a0487814787bcc2e6b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dc24d83df2f1b4125d5541e576a18e4f1fabf4aa51ffb55e1670055a3a7765aa/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/28c38b6e267cc02a806eb033998d90d5483e875283993bf15ebd6fb676445aa4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8b98e54ac5867901dfb899acd5c8c945f5ea98f69bc99ed4283cbbe5fd1a5b5e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c974a8bac2ab3fb407d73d379d1fd8e3ad2d5d37bd84d259aaf5d19dd8e4bb20/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf85ba34d9447973763b63e81351759ad4665a182bd42a12f2bf01416cb6236e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9dfb686f6a4c9bb5aac551ff50f6c89493e5d37229e8d0a90f1725a4a97b98eb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccbe6e85c920f45001435c90f2bd95d432e2908804631901c6eb00b0290e3a25/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39c609a115068695fe652ebe45e382b7a9b8651eaf9b9d0a1db631f4ca4352f9/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8acf9c4dcbc0241cdb938b766c1035c69716b44617ef8105ae5845ad70189ef8/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8acf9c4dcbc0241cdb938b766c1035c69716b44617ef8105ae5845ad70189ef8/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8acf9c4dcbc0241cdb938b766c1035c69716b44617ef8105ae5845ad70189ef8/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:02c055ef67f5904019f43a41ea5f099996d8e7633749b6e606c400526b2c4b33",
                "sha256:14be0d40572c9e789898075dab874a65268de67962d8fd775172b206a9305022",
                "sha256:e82f328cb5e68d3c0fcc6604b3c09a2898d94fde76f589abc5163c85e168a075",
                "sha256:b2abc2ad4a418fb408384c726f800fa1f722cbb38987200cd362bc73f20cc988",
                "sha256:570df12e998cd93e68915a6de7002f9ca1e4b21bbaca3cd1124b7770c800b1b4",
                "sha256:ae477702a51387de5407cbaad4e225c3b3ddfb329cb1b00739b4161fe34d80a6",
                "sha256:3182d4b853f01f95a1cc30cd97c3e5e4d1aa3011ba4cf6273c2d5b38ef1adba0",
                "sha256:940ffd6ceda5ac47aeabf50a3210969f1adce1a78b1dd66dab62c20a2c58caa5",
                "sha256:d329e0888b830d8de863fedf17cb8e600f46ff869b82a43d92499fceb7797bf8",
                "sha256:516d3b88eaf6e98711593913e66d73b14c4438aeec0ca57e6378823e7423ec6d",
                "sha256:8dd710df810d11d75e69cfd8dd0db15ebdd13a667069db0638b9d3168218b3f4"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id `69692152171a` is the first layer of the image and because you probably have another version of mysql locally that has the same layer as this one, when you did pull the image, this message `69692152171a: Already exists` means that there where no changes on that layer between versions.

To see the layers of an image run `docker image inspect mysql:5.7`

You can read more here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#examples

Comment: I have added UPD in question body with inspect output , but there is nothing related to 69692152171a

Comment: i think there is a mapping of some sorts when you download an image vs when you build it. If you run history `docker history mysql:5.7` shows missing on id. I found this link if it helps https://www.windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/

Comment: But the file can be found in this folder  `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/distribution/diffid-by-digest/sha256` and the complete sha is `69692152171afee1fd341febc390747cfca2ff302f2881d8b394e786af605696`

Comment: "The diff directory for storing the layer content, is now named after a randomly generated 'cache ID', and the Docker Engine maintains the link between the layer and its cache ID, so that it knows where to locate the layer's content on disk."